# OpenGL + libpng: wrong colors on image

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, png, gldrawpixels

Since last week I've been trying to load and show a PNG on the screen. I used a library libpng to copy png into memory and then used glDrawPixels to show it on screen. The result is following:

The original picture:

[image]

Screenshot in the "game":

[image]

And the code, I'm using static Image::loadPNG to load PNG into map and it's like the following:

```
bool Image::loadPNG( std::string _image, FILE * file, unsigned char header[ 54 ] )
{
    fseek( file, 8, SEEK_SET );
    ImageData* imageData = new ImageData( );
    Image* image = new Image( );
    image->type = IMAGETYPE_PNG;
    imageData->image = image;
    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct( PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL );

    if( !png_ptr )
    {
        std::cout << "png_create_read_struct failed. " << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);

    if( !info_ptr )
    {
        std::cout << "png_create_info_struct failed. " << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if( setjmp( png_jmpbuf( png_ptr ) ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Error during init_io. " << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    png_init_io( png_ptr, file );
    png_set_sig_bytes( png_ptr, 8 );
    png_read_info( png_ptr, info_ptr );
    png_set_strip_16( png_ptr );
    png_read_update_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    int bit_depth;
    int color;
    png_get_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, &image->width, &image->height, &bit_depth, &color, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_read_update_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    int pitch = png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    image->image = new unsigned char[pitch * image->height];
    png_bytep* row_pointers = new png_bytep[image->height];

    for (int y = 0; y < image->height; y++)
        row_pointers[image->height - 1 - y] = image->image + y * pitch;

    png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);
    delete[] row_pointers;

    // tym na razie dupy sobie nie zawracam

    Image::images.insert( std::pair< std::string, ImageData* >( _image, imageData ) );
    glGenTextures(1, &imageData->texture);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, imageData->texture );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image->width, image->height, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->image);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, image->width, image->height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->image );
    return true;
}
```

And finally showing it in OpenGL:

```
Image* image = Image::images["f.png"]->image;

if( image )
{
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPushMatrix( );
    //glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);  

    float nx = 0.0f;
    float ny = 0.0f;

    glLoadIdentity( );
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -1 );

    if( nx > 0 || ny > 0 )
        glRasterPos2f( nx, ny );

    else
    {
        glRasterPos2f( 0, 0 );
        glBitmap(0,0,0,0, nx, ny, NULL);
    }

    glDrawPixels( image->width, image->height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->image);
    glPopMatrix( );
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

As you can see, the colors are different than they should be. Could anyone help me to figure out how to solve my problem?

Comment: Why are you generating mipmaps when `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is set to `GL_NEAREST`?  Why are you generating textures *at all* if you're just going to use `glDrawPixels()`?

Comment: Thank you for finding minor issues in my application, I have fixed the first thing which you said, but relatively your second point, you might see my comment which in google translate would say something like "I don't care about following lines now". I would ask to concentrate in a major problem in the title.

Comment: The Image::images.insert should be above the comment also, nevermind that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have some color channels swapped. In the call to `glTexImage2D()`, try changing the `GL_BGRA_EXT` to `GL_RGBA`, I think. Or, if that doesn't work, change `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` to `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV`.

Comment: I have changed according to your hints, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your image is perhaps being drawn using a (multiply?) blend.

Do you have alpha blending enabled? (your image seems to have an alpha channel)

What blend mode have you set?

It should probably just be:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: I have exactly this and it's already inside function "init" of GLUT.

Comment: Have you set any scale and bias values for drawpixels?

Comment: How to? Could you explain?

Comment: You would have to set GL_RED_SCALE, etc. I don't really think that's the problem if you haven't already set it. What bit depth is the PNG?

Comment: The Properties window says it's 64x64 px, 32 bit image, so I think it's probably 24bit + alpha.

Comment: If you put a glDisable(GL_BLEND) right before DrawPixels, what does it look like?

Comment: This is really weird, if I put glBindTexture before if( image ) it shows PNG correctly!

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to add the image with blending disabled, and the bit about it drawing correctly with a glBindTexture() to your question. It might get a bit lost down here in the comment on an answer which isn't even correct!